# jQuery find td with exact number from List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a table and I need to find the td which has the exact number inside it (number '2'). The problem is the td numbers are lists like `1,2,3,4`.

Now if I do this, it finds the **`td`** with `'2'` inside:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

$(function(){
    var search = '2';
    $("table tr td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == search;
    }).css('color','red');
});
```

But if I do this, it doesn't work with lists:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1,14</td>
    <td>3,10</td>
    <td>2,5</td>
    <td>22,7</td>
  </tr>
</table>

$(function(){
    var search = '2';
    $("table tr td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == search;
    }).css('color','red');
});
```

What I want it to do is change all the numbers in that td 'red', for example 
2,5'.

Answer (score 2):

You could split by comma and check with includes.

```js
$(function(){
    var search = '2';
    $("table tr td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().split(',').includes(search);
    }).css('color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1,14</td>
    <td>3,10</td>
    <td>2,5</td>
    <td>22,7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are only searching for 2 but 2,5 is not a 2. But 2 is part of 2,5. 
My approach is simple I will split each node text with a , then I ll find whether 2 is present of not in that array

```
$(function(){
    var search = '2';
    $("table tr td").filter(function(x) {
        var t = $(this).text();
        var tArr = t.split(",")
        return tArr.indexOf(search) !== -1;
    }).css('color','red');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2on938m1/

Answer (score 0):

Try with includes.

```
$(function(){
    var search = '2,5';
    $("table tr td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().includes(search)
    }).css('color','red');
});
```

for example 
https://repl.it/repls/HandsomeLumberingEmulation