# Check if td element have certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table with number :

```
<td id="table-number">{{ $loop->index + 1 }}</td>
```

now i want to get the number of "9" from the table row

Here is what i do :

```
const number = document.getElementById('table-number');


if(number.textContent.includes('9')) {
            console.log('heyhey');
        }
```

but it returns nothing. So, what should i do? I expect to get the table number.

ok guys, i got the answer at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58390633/jquery-find-td-with-exact-number-from-list), sorry i didnt serach thoroughly. Need to upgrade my google skils

Comment: When does your JS run? Where is the `<script>` tag in relation to the `<td>` in your document?

Comment: So do you have 10 tds with the same id? id is supposed to be UNIQUE. So I am guessing your question is, how do I find the cell with the number 9 in it?

Comment: sorry gonna improve the post a bit

Comment: @epascarello should i change it to class?

Comment: @epascarello yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `<td>` elements are produced in a loop and you want to know if *any* of them contain a `9`, give the elements a class instead of id...

```html
<td class="table-number">
```

and try something like this instead

```js
const tableNumbers = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll(".table-number"),
  ({ textContent }) => textContent
);

if (tableNumbers.some((content) => content.includes("9"))) {
  console.log("heyhey");
}
```

Comment: this is much more straightforward. Working well.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need an id or a class on the cells.

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get a node list of all of the cells, coerce the node list to an array, and then [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the cell with the text content that includes your query.

```js
// Cache all the cells
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');

// Coerce the node list to an array on which you can
// use the `find` method to find the cell with the matching
// text
const found = [...cells].find(cell => {
  return cell.textContent.includes(3);
});

if (found) console.log(found.textContent);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: yesss that works well too. Thanks for the answer, you guys the best!!